# How to re-render an i frame with this.setState using ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, render

In a component, I am changing the state each time a button is clicked. The state is the url of the iframe. **The fact is, clicking a button does change the state (when printing it out, it works), but does not re-render the iFrame with the new url**. 
How comes ?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class VeryGoodConcept extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { url: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_ZKq471B2k' };
    this.changeVideo = this.changeVideo.bind(this);
}

changeVideo = (url) => {
    this.setState({ url });
    console.log(this.state.url);
}


render() {
    return (
        <div className="very-good-concept text-center">
            <h2 className="default-title">Le Very Good Concept</h2>
            <div className="row" id="video-row">
                <div className="col">
                    <button onClick={() => this.changeVideo("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_tlTXHAfBs")} className="btn video-btn"><h5><i className="fa fa-handshake-o"></i>   Le caractère caritatif ?</h5></button>
                    <div className="caritative text-right">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col presentation-video">
                    <iframe src={this.state.url}></iframe>
                </div>
                <div className="col">
                    <button onClick={() => this.changeVideo("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FuDv-sPXNoA")} className="btn video-btn"><h5><i className="fa fa-eur"></i>   La réduction fiscale ?</h5></button>
                    <div className="red-fiscale text-left">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button onClick={() => this.changeVideo("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_ZKq471B2k")} className="btn video-btn"><h5><i className="fa fa-users"></i>   Comment ca marche ?</h5></button>
        </div>
    );
}
}


 export default VeryGoodConcept;
```

**EDIT** : The issue was with the IFrame library I was using, which was not compatible with react ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a add a key which you mutate manually whenever you want the iframe to be re-rendered. Since you want the iframe to re-render on video url change, just use that as the key:

```
<iframe key={this.state.url} src={this.state.url}></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer!  It seems to me that I have another problem now ... `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.` **The iframe gets duplicated when clicking on a button...**

Comment: @Louis, that's weird. It shouldn't do that. Perhaps something that isn't included in your snippet causes that? Either way, using a new key is sort of a hacky solution. Perhaps it's best if you just move the `iframe` to its own component where you can more easily use lifecycle methods and functions such as `forceUpdate()`.

Comment: I'll try to do so :) I think the problem I have is from Bootstrap interacting with React ...

Comment: I still got the same problem ... I opened another question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410581/failed-to-execute-removechild-on-node-with-reactjs-bootstrap-component-dup Thank's for your help anyway